# Prove that $f$ is not Riemann integrable.

Tags: analysis

If a function $f:[-2,3]\to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by

$f(x)=\begin{cases} 2|x|+1 \; ;\; \text{ if } x \in \Bbb Q \\ 0 \; ;\; \text{ if } x \notin \Bbb Q \end{cases}$

Prove that $f$ is not Riemann integrable.

What I came up with:
 $m_k=0$,$M_k=7$

Which implies $U(P,f)=35$ and $L(P,f)=0$, for any partition of $[-2,3]$. So the upper and lower integrals are not equal,
hence $f \notin {\mathscr R}[-2,3]$

Comment: You need to look up what $M_k$ means.  In most cases it will not be $7$.

Comment: Is $M_k$ not the suprenum of the function over the partition?

Comment: It depends on the k'th interval in the partition.

Comment: For instance if your partition is $P = (x_0,x_1,x_2) = (-2,0,3)$, then $M_1 = 6$, and $M_2$ = 7.

Comment: My book defines $M_k$ as the suprenum of the set of points $f(x)$ takes over any $x \in[x_{k-1},x_k]$. So should I assume that my partition is the whole domain here? Are you all telling me I'm wrong?

Comment: @user65384 You should look at **various** partitions of $[-2,3]$ not just one.

Comment: @user65384 Look at the example I gave you. Given that partition, you have two $M_k$, one for each of the subintervals $[-2,0]$ and $[0,3]$. So for that partition, $U(P,f) = 2 \cdot 6 + 3 \cdot 7 = 33$. But one example like this does not suffice. You need to consider all of the possible partitions at once to define the upper Darboux integral.

Answer (score 4):

**ADD** It seems you're being given Darboux's approach to integration. I guess that for each partition $P=\{a=x_0,\dots,x_n=b\}$ of the interval $[a,b]$ you're defining 
$$M_k=\sup_{x\in[x_{k-1},x_{k}]}f(x)$$
$$m_k=\inf_{x\in[x_{k-1},x_{k}]}f(x)$$

and then the lower and upper sums of $f$ over $P$ as $$U(f,P)=\sum_{k=1}^n M_k(x_k-x_{k-1})$$

$$L(f,P)=\sum_{k=1}^n m_k(x_k-x_{k-1})$$

and the the lower and upper integrals (which always exist) as

$$\overline{\int_a^b}f=\inf\{U(f,P):P\text{ is a partition of }[a,b]\}$$

$$\underline{\int_a^b}f=\sup\{L(f,P):P\text{ is a partition of }[a,b]\}$$

The prove a function is **not** Riemann (equiv. Darboux) integrable, you can show those last number differ. But you have to try **many** partitions to see what is really going on, since the supremum and infimum are taken when $P$ varies throughout **all possible** partitoins of $[a,b]$. In particular, $M_k$ and $m_k$ will usualy vary for different partitions, as the comments show.

---

I hope you can see that $$\underline{\int_{-2}^3} f=0$$

Now you have to prove that $$\overline{\int_{-2}^3} f$$ is bounded away from zero, and you'll have proven the integral cannot exist.

To prove both assertions, use that both the irrationals and rationals are dense in $\Bbb R$. For each partition $P=\{-3=x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{n-1},x_n=2\}$, can you see why

$$\inf_{[x_{k-1},x_k]}f(x)=0$$

for any interval in the partition, for example?

On the other hand, what is the minimum value $2|x|+1$ takes on $[-2,3]$? What does this tell you, plus the density of $\Bbb Q$ on $\Bbb R$ about  $$\overline{\int_{-2}^3} f\text{ ? }$$

Comment: This was very helpful to me, thank you for going into such detail Pedro.

Answer (score 3):

Let $g:[-2,3]\to\mathbb R$ and $h:[-2,3]\to\mathbb R$ be defined by $g(x)=0$ and $h(x)=2|x|+1$ for every $x$. Then every lower integral of $f$ is a lower integral of $g$ and every upper integral of $f$ is an upper integral of $h$ (can you show this?).

Furthermore, $g$ and $h$ are continuous hence integrable. Thus, for every partition $P$,
$$
L(P,f)=L(P,g)\leqslant\int_{-2}^3g(x)\mathrm dx=0,
$$
and
$$
U(P,f)=U(P,h)\geqslant\int_{-2}^3h(x)\mathrm dx=c\gt0.
$$
This proves that $U(P,f)-L(P,f)\geqslant c$ for every partition $P$ hence $f$ is not Riemann integrable.